# Автоматическая прокрутка при добавлении строки в QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtablewidget

Использую *PyQt5*, есть таблица `QTableWidget`. Как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении строк и как дойдет до конца окна, была автоматическая прокрутка?

Посмотрел на `QTableWidget::scrollToBottom`, `QTableWidget::scrollToItem`. 
Не совсем понял как использовать, прошу помочь.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
import time

iteration = 0

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(1051, 736)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 1031, 671))
    self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1051, 24))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    
    self.timer = QTimer()
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_table)
    self.timer.start(1000 * 1)
           
    #self.update_table()

def update_table(self):
    print("update")
    global iteration
    print(iteration)
    #self.tableWidget.setItem(iteration,0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Item 1"))
    #self.tableWidget.setItem(iteration,1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Item 2"))
    #self.tableWidget.setItem(iteration,2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Item 3")) 
    #self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.tableWidget.insertRow(self.tableWidget.rowCount());
    iteration = iteration + 1       

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
# main
import sys
from ids import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__=="__main__":
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
myapp = MyWin()
myapp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста ваш пример с добавлением строк в `QTableWidget`

Comment: @S.Nick привел код, можешь пожалуйста показать на примере этого кода. С button не совсем понял

Comment: я добавил обновление, пробуйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QTableWidget::scrollToItem(const QTableWidgetItem *item, QAbstractItemView::ScrollHint hint = EnsureVisible)
>
> Прокручивает view при необходимости, чтобы убедиться, что item виден.
> Параметр hint более точно указывает, где должен находиться элемент после операции.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class InputBox(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(InputBox, self).__init__(parent)
        open_message = QtWidgets.QLabel("Введите данные для 1-й колонки:")
        self.txt     = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        save         = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Save',   clicked=self.accept)
        cancel       = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Cancel', clicked=self.reject)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addWidget(open_message, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.txt, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(save, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(cancel, 2, 1)
        self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint())

    def save(self):
        value = self.txt.text()
        return value
        

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(6, 2) 
        add = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add', clicked=self.add_button)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        grid.addWidget(add)

    def add_button(self):
        input_box = InputBox()
        input_box.setWindowTitle("InputBox Dialog")
        if input_box.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            val = input_box.save()
            it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(val)
            rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 0, it) 
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Hello World"))
            
            self.tableWidget.scrollToItem(it)                     # <----

Stylesheet = ("""
QScrollBar:vertical {              
    border: none;
    background: white;
    width: 3px;               
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
    stop: 0 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));
    min-height: 0px;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
    stop: 0 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130),  stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));
    height: 0px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
    stop: 0  rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130),  stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));
    height: 0 px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
""")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)
    window = Widget()
    window.setWindowTitle('Demo QTableWidget.scrollToItem')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> привел код, можете, пожалуйста, показать на примере этого кода. С button не совсем понял.

1. **Никогда** не изменяйте модуль созданный в QT Designer
2. Глобальные переменные - это **зло**.

Я отметил строки, которые изменил в вашем примере. Пробуйте.

```
import sys
#import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
#from ids import *

#iteration = 0  

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(900, 600)                                 # (1051, 736)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 900, 600))  # (10, 20, 1031, 671)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1051, 24))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

#        self.timer = QTimer()
#        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_table)
#        self.timer.start(1000 * 1)

#    def update_table(self):
#        print("update")
#        global iteration
#        print(iteration)
#        #self.tableWidget.setItem(iteration,0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Item 1"))
#        #self.tableWidget.setItem(iteration,1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Item 2"))
#        #self.tableWidget.setItem(iteration,2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Item 3")) 
#        #self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
#        self.tableWidget.insertRow(self.tableWidget.rowCount());
#        iteration = iteration + 1       

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
#        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)               # +++
        grid.addWidget(self.tableWidget)                               # +++

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_table)
        self.timer.start(1000 * 1)        

    def update_table(self):
#        global iteration
        
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        print(f"rowPosition = {rowPosition}")
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)

        it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(rowPosition))

        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 0, it)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Item 2"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Item 3"))         
        
        self.tableWidget.scrollToItem(it)                            # <<----<
        

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]