# Автопрокрутка в listWidget PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, listwidget

У меня имеется небольшое приложение написанное на python. Интерфейс создан при помощи Qt Designer. Данная программка является голосовым помощником, который также управляется при помощи голоса. Ответы программы добавляются слева, а запросы пользователя с права. Хотелось бы узнать можно ли в listWidget реализовать автопрокрутку при добавлении текста. Чтобы самому постоянно не прокручивать данный виджет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо, что уделили время моему вопросу).

Comment: Да, есть scrollToItem https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#scrollToItem

Comment: И еще есть scrollToBottom https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#scrollToBottom и scrollToTop() если список растет сверху

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1065862 ?